# A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I'm exposing a stored procedure via a `SqlQuery` in an Azure .NET backend with App Service. When the query is executed though, I get this error:

```
A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name
```

I'm not exactly sure why the data reader is trying to reference/map to the `Id` column because it's not part of the columns I select from the sproc query.

This is my code:

```
//Creating the stored procedure

CREATE PROCEDURE IndividualAverages @AccountId nvarchar,@StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN

print 'SELECT DISTINCT AccountId,AlertDate,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Version,Deleted, (CAST(Consumed AS real) / Total - Pending) * 100 AS Percentage FROM dbo.Statistics WHERE AccountId = @AccountId AND AlertDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate'

END
```

And this is my SqlQuery:

```
var paramId = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@userId", user_accountId.Trim());
var paramDateStart = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StartDate",newStartDate.ToUniversalTime());
var paramDateEnd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@EndDate", newEndDate.ToUniversalTime());

//This is where I execute the stored procedure
var userAverage = context.IndividualAverage.SqlQuery("EXEC dbo.IndividualAverages @userId,@StartDate,@EndDate" , paramId, paramDateStart, paramDateEnd).ToList();
```

Comment: In proc IndividualAverages , do you want to print the query or execute the query

Comment: Your procedure doesn't do anything. Not sure why you have a print line as the only line in your procedure. That should probably be a select statement???

Comment: Or error message is not related to code you have written in the post.

Comment: There is no `Id` columns selected in your query, but you are probably still using it somewhere in your code (if it would actually returns something at all, like @SeanLange mentioned)

Comment: Amit I execute the query on this line:                                                   var userAverage = context.IndividualAverage.SqlQuery("EXEC dbo.IndividualAverages @userId,@StartDate,@EndDate" , paramId, paramDateStart, paramDateEnd).ToList();

Comment: SeanLange this line should actually execute the query and returns a list var userAverage = context.IndividualAverage.SqlQuery("EXEC dbo.IndividualAverages @userId,@StartDate,@EndDate" , paramId, paramDateStart, paramDateEnd).ToList();

Comment: Right I see that you are executing the procedure. But look at the procedure, it has one line which is a print. It does nothing.